How can I initialize a class instance in a component in React?
I'm developing a very simple component that is capable of adding new items to an Array that is controlled by useState.
The name of my component is ListComponent, see the code below:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ListComponent = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([
        { title: 'Item 1' },
        { title: 'Item 2' },
        { title: 'Item 3' }
    ]);

    const addNewItem = () => {
        const newList = [...list, { title: `Item ${list.length + 1}` }];
        setList(newList);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h2>List of Items:</h2>
            {list.map((item, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                </div>
            ))}
            <button onClick={addNewItem}>Add new Item</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListComponent;

As you can see, the component starts with an Array of 3 items, and when clicking the addNewItem button, Javascript adds another item to the Array, so that the user can view it in real time (thanks to useState).
However, let's suppose that I wanted to abstract part of the logic of this component into a service called listService.js.
To do this, I created a new file inside the services folder called listService.js:
class ListService {
    constructor() {
        this.list = [
            { title: 'Item 1' },
            { title: 'Item 2' },
            { title: 'Item 3' }
        ];
    }

    getList(){
        return [...this.list];
    }

    addNewItem(){
        const newList = [...this.list, { title: `Item ${this.list.length + 1}` }];
        this.list = newList;
    }
}

export default ListService;

Finally, I needed to adapt the logic of my ListComponent component as follows:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ListService from '../../services/listService';

const ListComponent = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    const listService = new ListService();

    useEffect(() => {
        loadList();
    }, []);

    const loadList = () => {
        setList(listService.getList());
    }

    const addNewItem = () => {
        listService.addNewItem();
        loadList();
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h2>List of Items:</h2>
            {list.map((item, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                </div>
            ))}
            <button onClick={addNewItem}>Add new Item</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListComponent;

Initially this code can load the Array of components perfectly and even add "Item 4".
The problem is that the next time the user clicks the addNewItem button no item is added, as ReactJS always overwrites "Item 4".

I would like to know why ReactJS is not updating the Array.
Are there design patterns (like separation of responsibility) that ReactJS can't support?

Quick question: why are you using a useEffect instead of setList(listService.getList())? You already have your list, why force that double render of an empty list and then the real list when you can just render the real list immediately?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I decided to do it this way because in useEffect I load the list before the component is shown on the screen. Is this Wrong?

No, you don't: useEffect runs after the component renders. It's for running side effects that are unrelated to what React needs to do (e.g. external network requests, calling other libraries that have their own DOM manipulation, etc) after your component is done rendering itself.

The instance of the class will be new every time the state is changed. That is, each component render creates a new instance of the class ListService. You will take the creation of an instance of the class beyond the functional component.

That has nothing to do with SOLID.
Everytime react renders a component the function is executed including all code in it.
So when you call setList a new ListService will be instantiated because setList updates states which triggers rerender of component.
Either replace list service with const listService = useMemo(() => new ListService(), []) or like mentioned in comments load the list using useEffect and manage state in component from now on.
const [list, setList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setList(new ListService().getList());
}, []);

But because ListService.getList() is not async we can also just do:
const [list, setList] = useState(new ListService.getList())


Of course, that useEffect completely negates the point of using a service that you can directly call API functions on, as there is now no list service available to the rest of the function.

Yes but there were so many questions i tried to answer each a bit. The service itself is useless because it mimics the components behaviour or vice versa and i didnt want to include the whole context example because the question was more focused on why its not updating correctly.

Every state update will trigger a GUI re-render and with this comes the recalculating of non-memoized values and even some memoized values (when memory becomes a constraint).
With this in mind, construct ListService in such a way that it will not be re-constructed upon each re-render.
const listService = useRef()
useEffect(() => listService.current = new ListService(), [])
This constructs a ListService instance and takes a reference to it using listService. This reference will be the same across each re-render. You can use it in your other procedures like so:
const loadList = () => {
    setList(listService.current.getList());
}
const addNewItem = () => {
    listService.current.addNewItem();
    loadList();
}

In addition to this answer.
If your component can be unmounted and re-mounted during the application lifecycle, and the data needs to be saved, then you can create an instance of the class outside the functional component
import ListService from '../../services/listService';

const listService = new ListService();

const ListComponent = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(listService.getList()); // first init
  // Or after first render
  useEffect(() => {
    setList(listService.getList());
  }, []);
}


You don't need to use useEffect at all. Call listService.addNewItem() inside the addNewItem() on button click and set the new list as the state. Run the snippet to see it in action.


const { useState } = React;

class ListService {
  constructor() {
    this.list = [{ title: "Item 1" }, { title: "Item 2" }, { title: "Item 3" }];
  }

  getList() {
    return [...this.list];
  }

  addNewItem() {
    const newList = [...this.list, { title: `Item ${this.list.length + 1}` }];
    this.list = newList;
  }
}

const listService = new ListService();

const AddNewItem = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(listService.getList());

  const addNewItem = () => {
    listService.addNewItem();
    setList(listService.getList());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>List of Items:</h2>
      {list.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h3>{item.title}</h3>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={addNewItem}>Add new Item</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(<AddNewItem />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



